# Nginx-Remove WWW from HTTPS

Tags: ssl, nginx, rewrite

I would like to ask for some help with the following Nginx configuration, so that URLs such as `https://www.mywebsite.com` get rewritten as `https://mywebsite.com`. I am currently using the following configuration:

```
server {
    server_name www.mywebsite.com;
    return 301 $scheme://mywebsite.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mywebsite.com;

    # Some more settings...
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mywebsite.com;

    ssl_certificate path_to_ssl_certificate;
    ssl_certificate_key path_to_ssl_certificate_key;

    # Some more settings...
}
```

In case that matters, the certificate I am using is a wildcard SSL certificate that was self-signed using OpenSSL on the server itself (Ubuntu 12.04). What is happening is that `www.mywebsite.com` correctly redirects to `mywebsite.com`, but `https://www.mywebsite.com` *does not* redirect to `https://www.mywebsite.com` (i.e., the `www` still appears when viewing the page in a browser). What can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is fixing first server block to this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    server_name www.mywebsite.com;
    return 301 $scheme://mywebsite.com$request_uri;
}
```

E.g. you forgot to catch www.mywebsite.com connections on ssl port, that's all. By the way, it's the best way to remove www from site name, good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect happens in a virtual host only listening on port 80. To redirect requests coming in over SSL you need a virtual host listening on port 443 with SSL. Unless your browsers all support [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), you can only have one SSL virtual host, and so the rule needs to go into your existing SSL `server` block.

```
if ($host = www.mywebsite.com) {
    rewrite ^ https://mywebsite.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Comment: Downvoted because of http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil